# After adding the api key in map activity which i created in kotlin android studio there is no marker showing on the map

Tags: android, api, kotlin

I am adding the map activity in my android app but when i follow and add the google api key, it show the map, but the map has no marker in it.

It is supposed to have a marker on Sydney, according to the code.

```
package com.hari.rideit.Adapters

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.hari.rideit.R

class MapsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback,GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    map = googleMap

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    val myPlace = LatLng(40.73, -73.99)  // this is New York
    map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(myPlace).title("My Favorite City"))
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPlace))
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true)
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
}

override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker?)=false

}
```

Comment: Hi, you gave new york location and checking for Sydney. Please check the lat long once.

Comment: sorry its a typing mistake i want to set it to new york

Comment: What do you have as output?

Comment: just the world map but no marker

Comment: can you post your xml code?